# How to convert a compound path to a standard path in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I've got a ExtendScript that only works with paths and I've got a compound path, so how can I convert my compound path into a path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Pathfinder -> Expand should work` - if not could you post a screenshot of Illustrator?

Comment: Yeah that's right, turns out I was trying to do something that didn't really work very well with paths, oh well, cheers Jon!

Answer (score 23):

The `expand` option does not break apart your compound path, but the objects it consists of - you will still have a compound path.

To break apart the compound object, go to `Object > Compound path > Release`.

Comment: I have a `<Compound Path>` selected in the Layers palette, but the `Object > Compound path` sub-menu is entirely disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Please try release compound path with the right click. Then <kbd>Ctrl/Option</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>: `Object -> Path -> Join`

Answer (score 1):

If "compound path" are two pathes combined using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>, then maybe you could use the following:

[image]

Else you'd have to uncompound them (don't know what the ExtendedScript does).

Answer (score 1):

Release your compound path into its original parts, select them. Open the pathfinder menu and click 'merge'.

Answer (score 0):

I did this with a text that had not the BOLD option and it works with everything:

1. TEXT MENU / CONVERT TO PATHS
2. OBJECT MENU / EXPAND / (FILL AND STROKE OPTIONS CHECKED)
3. PATHFINDER PALETTE / ADD TO SHAPE AREA
4. OBJECT MENU / EXPAND APPEARANCE

In your case follow from step 3.

I hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and nothing worked until I took the compound paths using the layers panel and dragged them out of the the parent "group", then I used the Pathfinder to exclude the top layer (a compound path)).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this:

[image: Hope this helps!]

Greetz!

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just drop an image and call it a day; WRITE your answer.